# Remove InvisiblePrefixScriptBase message

Tags: notebooks

I have accidentally deleted a successful A=A.nb, but have a paper printout A` of it.

I have then taken a similar B = B.nb and hand-entered/edited it using A' to  reproduce A; call it C = C.nb.

C does not run properly, and I get a `InvisiblePrefixScriptBase` message.

How do I use paper A' to (re)create a good A?

(I am as ignorant as I seem, and would appreciate any advice)

Answer (score 1):

It is likely you typed in a character or characters that Mathematica doesn't like.

Try the following.

1. Exit from Mathematica if it is still open on your system.
2. Relaunch a new Mathematica session.
3. Open C.nb in the new session. If you get the error message immediately, report that back here.
4. If you do **not** get the error message immediately, proceed.
5. Evaluate each input cell one-by-one until you get the error message.
6. Select the input cell the produced the message, and select **Show Expression** from the **Cell** menu.
7. Examine the cell expression carefully. Look for strange unicode characters. They will appear as `\:nnnn`, where the `n`s represent hexadecimal digits. Such characters are likely the source of your problem.
8. Return the selected cell to normal display by selecting **Show Expression** from the **Cell** menu once again.
9. Make a new, empty input cell. Type what you think is the correction to the bad cell into this cell.
10. Evaluate the new cell. If it evaluates correctly, delete the bad cell. You can now evaluate the rest of the notebook.
11. If the new cell does not evaluate correctly, report back here, showing the showing the bad cell in its cell expression form; i.e., edit your question by adding an image of the bad cell in expression form.

Hope this helps.